# Vector drawing app for Android

Tags: android, vector-graphics, drawing

On my tablet (Android 4.4.2) I would like to be able to make vector drawings using the touchscreen. Many apps exist that can do vector drawings but they seem to focus either on handwritten notes or drawing predefined shapes while I would like to have both. On my PC I use Adobe Illustrator and I am pretty sure that something as extensive as that doesn't exist for Android, but I would like to get your recommendations on an app with the following features:

**Must haves**

- Freehand drawing of vector lines
- Drawing of preset shapes (most importantly: straight lines, elliptical shapes and rectangles)
- Save to common vector file format (e.g. EPS, PDF or SVG)

**Must have at least one of these**

- Text support (i.e. non-handwritten text)
- Color filling of closed contours (paintbucket)
- Cutting and joining of already drawn paths
- Ability to load raster images into the document

I would be surprised if such an app exists free of charge so a small cost is not an issue, as long as it is a one time price, not a monthly renewal thing.